# How center an image with Bootstrap (and React)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with Bootstrap.
I want to center an image but with the following code, the image is left-aligned:

HTML:

```
<div className="App vh-100">
  <div className="d-flex h-70 border border-white container">
    <div class="py-5">
      <div className="text-center">
        <img src={logo} className="esc-logo slide-top center-block" alt="logo" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container h-auto">
     <h1>test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS :

```
.App {
text-align: center;
background-color: #1e0933;
background-image: url(url);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;

}

.esc-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
}
```

What is wrong ? Somebody can help me pls ?

Thanks for your help,
hug0

Comment: Everything looks good, see stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chvfbq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is centered. The main problem is that the DIV with class `py-5` is not full width, so there's no room for the image to be centered in.

As a quick test I added `style={{width: "100%"}}` to the DIV with class `py-5`, and the image was centered.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App vh-100">
      <div className="d-flex h-70 border border-white container">
        <div className="py-5" style={{width: "100%"}}>
          <div className="text-center">
            <img
              src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_16fb061b0aa%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_16fb061b0aa%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2274.421875%22%20y%3D%22104.65%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
              className="esc-logo slide-top center-block" alt="logo"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container h-auto">
        <h1>test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See it live [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-night-druob?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)